# List all innerText contents of a TagName that is dynamically created while scrolling through Youtube

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm working on a Javascript project while learning, and my objective is to retrieve the titles of all the videos on my Youtube Homepage, along with the titles which get dynamically added while scrolling.

I was able to list the innerText of a particular tag which contained titles of all the initially loaded videos along with some additional data using this simple code : (I'm planning to extract the titles from the string obtained)

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("ytd-rich-item-renderer"); // This is dynamic (n elements)

for(i of videos){
  console.log(i.innerText)
}
```

However, **the result obtained is limited to a few videos and does not update when a new set of videos get loaded** (while scrolling). I believe Youtube renders/loads videos through *Grids*. So every time I reach the end of an initial set of videos (that loads on every refresh), it fetches for videos, and new grids are dynamically added.

The `<ytd-rich-item-renderer>` tag element gets dynamically added for every new loaded video. The parent component of every `<ytd-rich-item-renderer>` tag element is `<ytd-rich-grid-renderer>` :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ytd-rich-item-renderer")[0].parentComponent
```

```
Output : <ytd-rich-grid-renderer class="style-scope ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer" full-bleed="" style="--ytd-rich-grid-items-pe…-slim-items-per-row: 9;">
```

How can I modify this code to get a list of all `<ytd-rich-item-renderer>` elements that were being added dynamically in real-time while scrolling? (My end-goal is to create an extension)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you can detect changes in DOM see post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom